# SSAS / MDX Query - Show data between 2 dates

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a query:

```
select non empty
order ([Item].Children
,([Measures].[Total Line Value]
,[January 2010])
,DESC)
on Columns,
non empty
[January 2010]
on Rows
from [Sales Analysis]
where [Measures].[Total Line Value]
```

This query shows, in order from highest to lowest, the total sales a particular item has made for the month January 2010. What I would like to do is show the total sales an item has made between 2 specified dates, say January 2010 - March 2011. It just has to be the total value and not the value for each month. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "WITH" statement to declare new measure

```
Sum({[Your dim-n].[January 2010]:[Your dim-n].[March 2011]}, [Measures].[Total Line Value])
```

Use this new measure on the axis Rows and remove WHERE clause.

p.s. I can't test it now, so I can make a mistake :).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I forgot to use the sum in the WITH statement.